# Is segmented (piecewise) regression possible with a dichotomous dependent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, piecewise-linear

I have created a model of American cities with a dichotomous Y variable using logistic regression. I have theoretical reasons to believe that the model will differ significantly between larger and smaller cities. I have shown this using arbitrary breakpoints, but wanted to know if a segmented (piecewise) regression strategy can identify a breakpoint for me in a model with a binary dependent variable. (I have used the "nl" command successfully in Stata for a different project when the Y was continuous.)

Can I use this strategy to statistically identify a breakpoint? Or should I build the case for a number I pick otherwise?

Many thanks.

Comment: this isn't a statistical answer, but {segmented} package should provide you with breakpoint. there are many other approaches.

Comment: Your title question seems quite different from the two questions in the body of your text. The title question is easily answered (yes). Can you clarify what is intended by "statistically identify"?

Comment: Glen, Sorry for the confusion between title and text. Am still learning all this. My understanding is that segmented regression identifies the x value when the slope (i.e.coefficient) changes. However, with logistic model, there is not the same kind of slope (at least how I picture it.) So will the same strategy (i.e. segmented regression) work? Or are their other strategies? I essentially want to run two models - one for big cities and one for small - but there is no common definition for what size goes in each category. My hope is I could use segmented regression to tell me.

Comment: Charles, Thanks for your note. What other approaches would you consider or recommend?

Comment: (1) I'd model first assuming not breakpoint. With stata there are a number of options (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-07/msg00305.html) including GAM (generalized additive models), mkpline=splines, and smoothers. (2) for breakpoint, segmented has given best results. But could use MARS/EARTH package in R.